# CMake undefined reference to a function from my library used in my executable

Tags: c++, c, cmake, linker

I've been struggling with this problem for so long that now it's my time to get your time wasted with an easy question. I'm trying to link a small cpp project using CMake and it's a pain for me - I have no idea how to do that and I'm stuck in a loop of getting the same 3 errors over and over. I think my fundamental understanding of CMake and linking might be wrong.

So this is my directory structure:
[my dir structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7IhN.png)

For people who don't want to change websites:

```
/src
main.cpp
game.cpp
/include
game.h
```

game.h contains definitions for functions in game.cpp, which are used by main.cpp.

I have no idea how should I structure the CMakeLists.txt file. Btw, I'd also like to have the SDL2 library linked and I'm using some sort of a solution that finds the lib dirs and links them.

So, when it comes to the cmake code (which I assume is a total mess)

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
    project(game)

    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
    
    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp include/game.h)
    add_library(mylib src/game.cpp include/game.h)
    target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE include/game.h)
    link_directories(src include)
    INCLUDE(FindPkgConfig)
    PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(SDL2IMAGE REQUIRED SDL2_image>=2.0.0)
    PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(SDL2 REQUIRED sdl2) include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
    target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2IMAGE_LIBRARIES} mylib)
```

And when it comes to the error I get it's a load of those:

```
main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `Game::initGame()' main.cpp:14: undefined reference to 'Game::quit()'
```

I assume the main.cpp knows about game.h, but has no idea about game.cpp existing and having the actual definitions.

I tried all the solutions on the web and I'm stuck in the whirlwind of repeating errors.

Comment: You got a executable and a lib. Your executable needs to _link_ to that lib.

Answer (score 1):

`target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE include/game.h)` should be `target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE include)` (it's in the name: you specify include *directories*). But really what I'm assuming you actually want is `target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC include)`.

`link_directories(src include)` is for specifying directories that contain things that you link to. ([docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_directories.html)). Unless your source and include directories contain things you want to link to, I don't understand why you would do this. And in general, it's recommended not to use things like `link_directories` unless there's a really good reason, and instead use the target-specific commands.

Assuming `Game::initGame` is defined in your `mylib` target, you should be doing `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE mylib)`.

I'm not sure what `mylib` is doing in your `target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2IMAGE_LIBRARIES} mylib`. Is `mylib` a directory containing things you want accessible in your `#include`s in your executable target? If you actually just want the include directories of `mylib` accessible by your executable target, this will be covered when you do the `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: so now i tried to simplify it all - moved everything into the same dir, removed sdl library includes for now and my CMakeFiles.txt looks like that: 
`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(game)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
add_library(mylib game.h game.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE mylib)`
still getting the same error, and thank you very much for the answer, i hope we'll be able to work out the solution

Comment: Read my first paragraph again. You're missing `target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC include)`.